# Save MATLAB subplot as PDF

Tags: matlab, pdf

In my project i have 10 subplot commands. I want the subplots to be saved in PDF format. I tried by using `saveas(gcf,'Trial_Plot.pdf')` command at the end of all these subplot commands, then i get a PDF with all the subplots in a crowded manner (with large margins in the PDF). 
How can I avoid this? Is it possible to create the PDF for the first subplot command, then for the rest the subplots are appended to that same PDF? Is this appending method possible ?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: You want to have each of the 10 subplots on different pages in the PDF? And the PDF page size should be exactly the same size as the subplot, so there are no margins?

Comment: afaik a subplot is not a separate entity. I'd create 10 `plot` figures (so not subbed) with `'visible', 'off'` and save those 10 as PDF

Comment: @hbaderts Actually i want each subplot below the previous one, till the end of page. Then go to next page for next subplot. I.e. I dont want all the subplots to crowd into a single sheet... If required it may use the next page.

Comment: @krishna have you tried using matlab "print" instead of saveas and specifying some of the options there ?

Comment: How to save different plots into different pages in a PDF?  Is there any possibility to do so? Kindly help me out. Currently all the plots are coming in different PDFs.